# Print specific date in python

Tags: python

I want to create a function that will return a date depending on each month. More specific I want it to return to me the 23d day of each month in the example format (YYYY, MM, DD):
`2018, 1, 23` .

except for the occasion that this date coincides with a weekend, in which I want it to return the exact previous working day. For example for December 2017 the 23d was Saturday, so in this case I want my function to return to me 
`2017, 12, 22`.

Right now I use:

```
import datetime
someday = datetime.date(2018, 1, 23)
    print(someday)
```

with which in the `someday` variable I define the desired date manually for each month.

In short for the next seven months of 2018 (January, February, March, April, May, June, July), I want my function to return to me :

```
2018, 1, 23
2018, 2, 23
2018, 3, 23
2018, 4, 23
2018, 5, 23
2018, 6, 22
2018, 7, 23
```

and so on and so forth for the next months.

Comment: hint: use a loop

Comment: use time delta to add month

Comment: if you have a datetime object such as `dt_object` use the `weekday()` function on it to get the day of the week. If this is larger than 5, it's a weekend.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a small python script on how you could do it.

Use `toordinal` to check for the day of the week and if it's Saturday or Sunday, subtract 1 or 2 by using `timedelta`

```
import datetime

# Yes, from 1,13 because 13 is exclusive (Goes only to 12)
days_month = datetime.monthrange(2018,x)
for x in range(days_month[0],days_month[1]+1):
    for x in range(1, monthrange):
        someday = datetime.date(2018, x, 23) # Loop over every month
        weekday = someday.weekday() # 0 = Monday, 6 = Sunday
        if(weekday > 5 ): # If it's "more" than Friday
            jumpback_days = weekday - 4; # Subtract 4 from the current weekday to get 1 for Saturday and 2 for Sunday
            print(someday - datetime.timedelta(days=jumpback_days)) # Subtract days and print
        else:
            # Print without subtracting anything
            print(someday)
```

Note: If you are using Python2, please replace `range` with `xrange` for it to work.

*EDIT:* If you want to print **only** and **all** workdays in a specific year, you can do it this way:

```
import datetime
from calendar import monthrange

year = 2018
for month in range(1, 13): # Yes, from 1,13 because 13 is exclusive (Goes only to 12)
    days_month = monthrange(year, month) # Request the amount of days in that month
    for day in range(1, days_month[1] + 1): # Iterate through all days of that month (+1 because it's exclusive)
        someday = datetime.date(year, month, day) # Loop over every month
        weekday = someday.weekday() # 0 = Monday, 6 = Sunday
        if(weekday < 5 ): # If it's "less" than Saturday
            # Print because if it's "less" than Saturday, then it's a workday
            print(someday)
```

Comment: For September and December of 2018 the 23d is Sunday so i should get back 2018-09-21 and 2018-12-21 respectively (Currently i get 2018-09-23 and 2018-12-23).

Comment: Thank you for you r reply. I actually meant that i want the function to return for a given month the requested date. Right now all the dates are printed out for 2018. What i want is that now (January) one day to be returned: 2018-23-01. In February i want 2018-23-02 etc.

Comment: @Adriano10 Check my answer now, it should work as you expect. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with `weekday()`, `timedelta()` and `while` loop:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

def last_workday(somedate):
    while somedate.weekday() > 4: #weekday returns values 0-6 (Mon-Sun)
        somedate -= timedelta(days=1) #timedelta returns 1 day which you subtract from your date 
    return somedate

y = 2018
d = 23

for m in range(1,13):
    print(last_workday(date(y, m, d)))
```

Comment: I'd use `day_of_week = somedate.weekday()` \n `if day_of_week > 4 : somedate -= timedelta(days=day_of_week - 4)`.  In other words, rather than doing the subtraction in a loop, calculate directly.  (OTOH, your method works better if we need to use `is_weekend_or_bank_holiday(somedate)`)

Comment: I chose this option to fit Sunday case where the output would be `2018-12-21`

Comment: Thank you for you r reply. I actually meant that i want the function to return for a given month the requested date. Right now all the dates are printed out for 2018. What i want is that now (January) one day to be returned: 2018-23-01. In February i want 2018-23-02 etc.

Comment: Yeah, but if you forward any date into `last_workday()` you'll get desired result. Loop is there just to showcase results.

Comment: Yes i know what you mean and thank you for helping. However, in an ideal situation i do not want to use manual input in order to get the desired date. I want when i run my function to only get the desired date (2018-01-23 for January 2018, this month)